# How do i fix this countertop hole?

Tags: kitchen-counters, hole-repair

[image: I]I have this decent size hole in my counter top. I have no idea in the home improvement world so anything would help. How do I fix this so it's not noticeable?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Probably no good way of fixing so it is not noticeable without recovering or replacing.   What you can do is to make a design feature to hide it.  Something like a built in pot holder/pad or just a built in design like a flower, a glass block.  Cut out a section of counter to fit new piece, with a piece of wood/plywood glued and screwed from underneath to support it.

Comment: What material is the countertop? What size is the hole? Please [edit] to add that information to your question.

Comment: Zoomed out picture would also be helpful to see what we're dealing with.

Comment: Invisibly patching the melamine laminate on the top is going to be nearly impossible. Your best bet would likely be to follow @crip659's advice, which he should write up as an answer. It's hard to tell what the substrate is made of - it almost looks like 2 layers of drywall. In any case, some plywood cut to fit (enlarge the hole to make nice square edges) and placed inside then secured would hold the melamine up.

Comment: Or this? [How can I repair my damaged kitchen counter?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/how-can-i-repair-my-damaged-kitchen-counter)

Comment: Or this? [How to repair this scratch in laminated countertop?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214089/how-to-repair-this-scratch-in-laminated-countertop)

Comment: Or this? [How can I repair a hole in wood laminate kitchen countertop?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52841/how-can-i-repair-a-hole-in-wood-laminate-kitchen-countertop)

Comment: Or this? [How do I repair this laminate bubble?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39367/how-do-i-repair-this-laminate-bubble)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I fix this

- Remove any loose pieces

  - Use a jigsaw to take care of ragged edges
- Attach a piece of 1/2-inch plywood to the bottom of the hole using 1-inch screws
- Fill in the hole with a 2-part epoxy
- Let the epoxy set
- Sand it to your desired satisfaction
- Buff the area to make it smooth

---

> so it looks unnoticeable?

Replace the entire countertop.

or

Re-laminate the entire countertop.